# Emailing to have a discussion

Tags: etiquette, email, professionalism

I am an undergraduate student in physics who has been self-studying certain subjects in humanities/social sciences due to the pandemic. I'd like to gain more perspective on the subjects, but have been unable to, due to the few people I know in the field and the quarantine.

There are interesting research papers, books, and articles (or even talks) in the fields I am studying, and I wonder how the author would feel should someone email them to simply talk about the topic they're writing. For example, an email about your opinion on the perception of reality based on their research papers, books, and maybe also from other sources. Is it okay to email the author to discuss what they're researching?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, cold emails are unlikely to lead to the sort of open-ended discussion you're looking for. I would guess that they would likely be ignored.

You might have better luck attending conferences -- possibly online, and possibly undergraduate-focused. They are a traditional venue in which to meet new people, and people might be more receptive there to invitations to chat about their work.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can email, but expect that almost every such mail will be ignored or (possibly) answered in only a perfunctory way. People are busy both with their own research and in working with their own students. Most such emails are likely to wind up in the trash.

As an undergraduate who wants to make contact with a professor at another institution, you can have better (not perfect) success if you work indirectly through one of your own professors. If I get an question from a student of another institution, my willingness to deal with it depends on my current workload (and work/life balance). I might be able to reply with a short note but not likely to start a longer conversation.

If I get an introduction to a student from another professor, however, I'd be much more likely to give it serious consideration, just as a courtesy to a colleague. And I would depend on that colleague to vet the seriousness of the person being introduced with some assurance that my time isn't  going to be wasted. I still can't guarantee that time and effort would be available, but you might make it past the door labelled Trash.

Answer (score 1):

I’d be more likely to answer an email from an undergraduate student that’s well written and has questions based on clearly having read the material. I get too many emails that start “Dear Professor” and then say something nice about my “lab” and how they’d like to join it. However, I’m not a professor and I have no lab, showing that they’ve done no prior research on me and my work. So, I just ignore those. However, an email that was properly addressed and came with questions about some specific elements of my prior work would be much more likely to get an answer.